# Setting the Last Selected Anchor Tag a Color - jQuery, HTML

Tags: jquery, html

*The question has gotten rewritten.*

## An Example:

Here is an example HTML page: http://jsfiddle.net/mwMzD/2/

## The Question:

When the `Third Page` link is selected, and the page is rendered, then the selected `anchor tag` should still keep the color ***"white"***, and not revert back to ***"grey"*** `(a:visited)`.

***Notice:** Do keep in mind that a:visited applies to every visited `anchor tag`, and not just the last selected `anchor tag`.*

Which `methods` are needed for this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a CSS class to the `Third Page` link when that page is rendered.

```
<%= link_to "Third Page", route_to_third_page_path, class: "active" if current_page?(route_to_third_page_path) %>
```

You'd then add this `.active` class to your `a:active` selctor

```
a:link { color: grey; }
a:visited { color: grey; }
a:hover { color: white; }
a:active, a.active { color: white; }
```

Now, when the `Third Page` renders, the `.active` class will be applied to the link, causing it to take on the same style as `a:active`.

---

**Edit** *Now that you've completely rewritten your question*

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/h67Ec/

Here is the jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
      $('a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active')
    });        
});​
```

and the styling from my original answer *(see above)* still applies.

Comment: Which methods would be needed with jQuery?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with jQuery; I don't know why you are retagging it as such.

Comment: Your question makes no reference to jQuery or some need to manipulate the DOM via Javascript through some hover event. If you'd like to update your question to include and explanation of such requirement I'd be happy to take a look and respond accordingly.

Comment: I just rewrote the question.